# Tortoise CVS merge branches

Tags: version-control, merge, cvs, branch

I have two branches `DEVELOPPEMENT` and `DEVELOPPEMENT2`.

[image: CVS merge]

I would like to merge `DEVELOPPEMENT` and `DEVELOPPEMENT2` into a same branch but **not** in the `HEAD` yet.

How to do it with the Tortoise HMI? I cannot find any documentation on that.

[image: Tortoise CVS Merge]

Comment: Cross posting isn't allowed. Please delete one of the questions.

Comment: This question appears to be [cross-posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680467/tortoise-cvs-merge-branches). Please don't do that.

Comment: @Sathya I deleted the question from Stackoverflow. Is Superuser the best place to post it?

Comment: @Maxbester between the two, [so] is probably better choice.. let me know if you don't get any responses in few days, I'll migrate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Tortise CVS, but the way to go about should be to switch your Working directory from HEAD to either *DEVELOPPEMENT* or *DEVELOPPEMENT2*

once switched, perform the merge, you should get the file in the same branch off which you're working. Then do the commit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However I don't understand the fields `Start`, `End` and `Bug`.

Comment: @Maxbester I believe start and end should mention the starting and ending revisions/branches which you want to merge. Bug is probably a comment which would get amended to commit message

Comment: So start should be `DEVELOPPEMENT2` and end should be `DEVELOPPEMENT`? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: @max I think start should be the older one & end shoould be the new one. You can try, the merge won't commit it, so just go ahead with the merge & see if it's okay & then commmit it

Answer (score 0):

Source: c:\Program Files\TortoiseCVS\UserGuide_en.chm

Merging from a Branch
When you are satisfied with the changes you have done on a branch, you may want those changes to be available on the head branch of development. Incorporating changes from one branch to another, is known as merging.

To merge from a branch, move your local copy to the branch you want to merge the changes into. See Selecting a Branch to Work On or Going Back to the Head Branch. Select the top level folder of the project. You can also select the exact folders and files that are part of the desired branch if you know this information. Right-click the on the selection, and choose CVS → Merge....

Merge Dialog
You will then be presented with the Merge Dialog. Here you can enter the branch name in the Branch to merge from field you wish to merge. Click the OK button, and TortoiseCVS will now merged the branch specified into your local copy. Your changes will not be made on the server repository, until you commit your changes.

Comment: Anything that are not your own words should be contained within a quote